# Storing user's application preferences in Terminal Services Server session. Managed C++

Tags: c++, managed, terminal-services

Sorry if my question is silly, but I have no experience at all with terminal server and am having a problem on how to store user preferences for an app.
The application was originally designed to run in individual, independent, computers. The installer has the option to install for all users or the current user but it always stores some xml in a subdirectory of the commonapp folder of the computer. It does store it here to be able to write to it later on under Windows vista upward.

Now, the company is running terminal server and the users don't have an independent computer anymore. They log into a session of terminal server and the administrator decides what software they can use. As the app is now, it installs in the server and offers all the users the same preferences from the commonapp. If the preferences are changed for an user, they all will have the change...

Please, could someone illustrate me on this? Initially, I though that by choosing 'to all users' when installing, the terminal server system would use the roaming folder of the user to store the preferences but I was wrong...
I don't know what users are going to use the app and cannot install directly to their folder either.
Is this a terminal server settings thing or do I have to write some code in the app that checks if the user has the xml in its folder and copy it and use it if it doesn’t?

Answer (score 0):

Do not store application preferences in its directory. Instead, store it in user's roaming directory - use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` (since you tagged the post as managed). Then it can be installed once, but run multiple times by multiple users and each of them will get his set of settings.

Comment: I am not installing the settings in the application path, as in modern windows systems the app can only write there running as administrator. I am storing them currently at Environment::SpecialFolder::CommonApplicationData which returns the commonAppdata or ProgramData in vista and above. I guess that the SpecialFolder::ApplicationData will do as you say. I'll give it a try and come back!:) Many thanks.